# Retrieve data from firebase database as values of a hashmap and displaying the key and value using react native

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, hashmap

I'm new to react native and firebase. I'm working with react native and firebase for an app. I have a database that contains the items from a store. I would like to retrieve that data as the values of a hashmap. The key of the hashmap would be the store name. I would like to display the store name (key) and the items (values) on the screen.

This is how my database looks like.

```
items
|------uniqueKey1
        |------item1
|------uniqueKey2
        |------item2
|------uniqueKey3
        |------item3
|------uniqueKey4
        |------item4
```

I just need some guidance on how to do this. Some pseudocode or explanation of the flow of the program would be greatly appreciated.